# Why $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$ converges pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

> Consider the geometric series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$. Does it converges pointwise in the interval $-1<x<1$?

Solution.

> The series has ratio $-x^2,$ thus the $n^{th}$ partial sum is $S_n=\dfrac{1-(-x^2)^{n+1}}{1+x^2}$.
>
> For each $x\in(-1,1)$ this converges to $1/(1+x^2),$ so the series does converges pointwise.

My question is:

Why does the series converge to $1/(1+x^2)$?

Why does $-\dfrac{(-x^2)^{n+1}}{1+x^2}$ tend to zero when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: If $|x| < 1$, then $(-x^2)^{n + 1}$ has absolute value $|x|^{2n + 2} \to 0$.

Comment: I don't understand, why $|x|^{2n + 2} \to 0$ ?

Comment: I also don't  understand the downvotes.

Comment: If you take a number whose modulus is less than $1$ and raise it to a high power, what do you get?

Comment: Got it now, thank you @T.Bongers

Comment: @T.Bongers Will this hold if $x\in[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @T.Bongers Why not? I know it definitely should not take 1 as upper limit but -1 can be taken right?

Comment: Well, what is different between $x$ raised to a large power for $x \in (-1, 1)$ and $\pm 1$ raised to a high power? Try to work it out.

Comment: @T.Bongers Is it because the serie would have the chance to converge to 3 possible numbers? 1,-1 and 0?

Comment: No, the series simply diverges if $x = \pm 1$, via the $n$-th term test.

Comment: $S_n= 1$ when n=even and $S_n=0$ when n=odd, thus $S_n$ diverges. Is this a correct argument?

Comment: No, that's not quite enough - $S_n \ne 0$ does not preclude convergence. But the $n$-th term test does.

Comment: @T.Bongers I modified, let me check what n-th term test is because my teacher hasn't taught me that test

Comment: @T.Bongers hope to not bother you too much :) .So n-th term test says if $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq 0,$ then $\sum a_n$ diverges. So we have that $ lim_{n\to\infty} f_n\neq 0$ when $x=\pm 1$, hence the serie must diverge.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @T.Bongers Is it correct to say that the series has ratio $r=-x^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does $\frac{(-x^2)^{n + 1}}{1 + x^2}$ tends toward zero when $n$ goes to infinity?

The answer is because $-1 < x < 1$. This means that $x$ can be written as a number $x = \pm\frac{1}{y}$, such that $y > 1$. This gives:

$$
(-1)^{n + 1}\frac{y^{-2n - 2}}{1 + \frac{1}{y^2}} = (-1)^{n + 1}y^2\frac{y^{-2n - 2}}{1 + y^2} = (-1)^{n + 1}\frac{y^{-2n}}{1 + y^2}
$$

This obviously tends toward zero since you have a negative exponential with a base, $y$, greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since domain is restricted in range$-1<x<1$ therefore if you tend the limit in your geometric series to $\infty$,  then the number $x$ must converge to a particular point which is probably $0$ as you are raising a very high power on a fractional number which converges the sum to $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.
Hope my answer is clear.

Comment: A limit in the ([tag:epsilon-delta]) definition is a fixed object.  How can you "tend the limit ... to $\infty$"?